# order results by date asc if column value is 1, otherwise date desc

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case, case-when

I have the following results in mysql; it is just two columns: `date` and `x`.  `date` is a timestamp and `x` is either `0` or `1`.

```
date       |  x
:--------- | -:
2020-02-13 |  1
2020-02-13 |  0
2020-02-01 |  1
2020-02-11 |  0
2020-02-11 |  1
2020-02-11 |  0
2020-02-12 |  1
2020-02-13 |  0
```

I want these results sorted as follows...
If the column x is equal to 1 then place these results at the top of the table and sort by date oldest to  newest.
if column x is equal to 0 then place these results at the bottom of the table and sort by date newest to oldest.

I'm coming close with the following code:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN x = '1' THEN 0 ELSE date END ASC
```

As column `x` is sorted correctly but the date is not as specified above.

Also, working with mysql.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Thank you! both worked...now I have to figure out why...

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
It first sort by X and then by date x=1 ascendig and X= 0 descending

```
SELECT 
`date`, `x`
FROM table1
order by
    x DESC,case when x = 1 then date end,
    date desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d32c7d/4/0

Comment: I have a strong deja-vu feeling when I read this answer after it was deleted and edited...

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
order by
    x desc,
    case when x = 1 then date end,
    date desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3f34f4a8ed951c55dc417f9f44a45fb)**:

```
date       |  x
:--------- | -:
2020-02-01 |  1
2020-02-11 |  1
2020-02-12 |  1
2020-02-13 |  1
2020-02-13 |  0
2020-02-13 |  0
2020-02-11 |  0
2020-02-11 |  0
```